# How to put the affiliations in the one column footnote in a two-column template?

Tags: pdftex

all, 
Could you help me to fix two problems:

1. how to put the affiliations ordered by number in the one column footnote in a two-column template? that is, changing the affiliations in the first picture to the format as the second picture.
2. how to make the abstract in the width of two-column? that is, changing the width of the abstract in the first picture as in the second picture.

For your convenience, here is the tex code, or you can directly go to [the overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/2845649285pbdhncsvzqkp). Thanks a lot in advance.

```
\documentclass[8pt, twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage{a4wide}

\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}  
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{empty}

\date{}
\begin{document} 
\title{\huge \bf Here is the title}
\author{AAA \thanks{A} \and BBB \thanks{B} \and CCC \thanks{C}}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    % \textcolor{red}{approximately 150 words.}
    \noindent \textbf{Abstract goes here Abstract goes here Abstract goes here Abstract goes here Abstract goes here Abstract goes here}
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\section*{}
introduction goes here 
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: hi, anybody can help me? I spent a lot of time to fix this problem, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**I figured out a way to address this issue. Hope this fixes your problem.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{orcidlink}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{multicol,blindtext,microtype}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, left=1in,right=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\footremember}[2]{%
\footnote{#2}
\newcounter{#1}
\setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}
\newcommand{\footrecall}[1]{%
\footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
}
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\title{\textbf{This is the title for someone who like to elaborate  discussion on pressing issues of people.}}
\author{%
\textbf{The Learner}\affmark[1] \orcidlink{0000-0002-0000-0000} \footremember{alley}{\affaddr{\affmark[1]Department of Mechanical Engineering, B. S Abdur Rahman Crescent Institute of Science and Technology, Vandalur, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India }}%
\and \textbf{The confused}\affmark[2] \orcidlink{0000-0003-0000-0000} \footremember{trailer}{\affaddr{\affmark[2]Department of Metallurgy, Indian Institute of Technology, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India }}%
\and \textbf{The admirer}\affmark[3] \orcidlink{0000-0004-0000-0000}  \footrecall{alley} \footnote{\affaddr{\affmark[3]Materials Science And Engineering, King Fahd University of Petroleum \& Minerals, Dhahran , Saudi Arabia } }%
\and \textbf{The successor}\affmark[4] \orcidlink{0000-0005-0000-0000} \footrecall{trailer} \footnote{\affaddr{\affmark[4]Department of Mechanical and Aerospace Engineering,  IITH Rd, Hyderabad, Telangana, India }}%
}
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\par\noindent\textbf{\abstractname}\ \textendash\ \ignorespaces}
{\par\medskip}
\date{}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
\kern -3pt
\hrule width \textwidth height 0.5pt
\kern 2pt
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \textbf{This is the abstract for the journal I am aiming to publish. This abstract that I will write in this area will be elaborated from the left-hand side of the document. Hence to do so, I need to put some commands in the preamble, after which everything will be excellent.}
\end{abstract}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \blindtext[3-5]
    \blindtext[6-8]
    \blindtext[9-11]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]